# Find an example infinite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, group-theory, infinite-groups

Find an example of an infinite group and a set of elements $\{g_{1},g_{2},\dots,g_{n},\dots\}$ of finite order with the property that if $$S_n=\cfrac{o(g_{1})+o(g_{2})+\cdots+o(g_{n})}{n}$$
then $\lim_{n\to \infty}S_{n}\in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$.

I would appreciate if someone can give me a hint!

Comment: First: What is for you "a sample group"? Second, what have you done so far?

Comment: @DonAntonio I can't find a group like it !

Comment: Again: what in the world is a "sample group"??

Comment: He means example I believe

Comment: Ok, I think I'm beginning to understand what the OP may have wanted to ask: "Find **an example** of an infinite group and a set of elements $\;\{g_1,...,g_n\}\;$ *of finite order* in it s.t. that they fulfill the property...." . If you write in english you really must be way more careful as sometimes things become very hard to understand.

Comment: @DonAntonio THX alot

Comment: [Do not re-post your questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903339/bring-an-infinite-sample-group). Edit them instead.

Comment: The algebra part here is quite irrelevant, you just have to find a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ of integers $\geq 2$ such that $S_n=\frac{a_1+\ldots + a_n}{n}$ converges to an irrational number. You may achieve that by choosing $a_n\in\{2,4\}$, so it is enough to consider the group given by the product of an infinite number of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/(4\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 3):

Take the infinite sum $\;G:=\bigoplus_{k\in\Bbb N}\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;$ , then for *any* non-unit elements $\;g_n\in G\;$ we have that $\;o(g_n)=2\;$ , so

$$S_n=\frac{o(g_1)+\ldots+o(g_n)}n=\frac{2+2+\ldots+2}n=2\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}2\in\Bbb Q^*$$

Comment: but i mean $\mathbb{Q^*}=\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @samansasani Sorry, but your notation is awkwards then: almost everybody means $\;\Bbb F^*:=\Bbb F\setminus\{0\}\;$ for a field...If you're going to use non-standard notation then *define it*!

Comment: @DonAntonio yeah you are right but i edit my questions

Comment: @samansasani, please do not use Persian here because we use English only on the SE.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay That is not accurate. The site not only allows but even encourages people that has problems with english to post in their native language, hoping some other member can understand the language and help. It can be certainly hard to find a language that most people handles besides english, but it is not off the line to use others.

Comment: @DonAntonio, Yes. Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Dear Don, sorry if I used unofficial language here. In fat I was to lead him about what he asked awkwardly. Believe or not this was the first time I did such this way. Also, I warn him about posting multiple questions frequently. :-)

Comment: @DonAntonio Since your answer doesn't match the intended question (due to the nonstandard notation of the OP, not your fault at all, but still), would you edit it to match?

Answer (score 0):

There exist groups which contain every element of finite order, for example
$$S_{\mathbb{N}}\:\:\text{ and }\:\:
\bigoplus_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}.$$
This means that your question reduces to one about series: find integers $\{i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_n, \ldots\}$ such that if $S_n=\frac{i_1+i_2+\cdots+i_n}{n}$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}S_{n}\in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$. Can you do this?

Note: by $S_{\mathbb{N}}$ I mean all permutations of the integers. The element $(1,2,3,\ldots,n)$ has order $n$.

Comment: nice idea let me try!